# How do I access a variable in the request scope in JSP from a Spring MVC controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, el

I have the following in my controller

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(name="userId", required=true) String userId) {
    if (userId.matches("^\\d+$")) {
        return "login";
```

And I have the following in my `login.jsp`

```
    User: <input type="text" name="userId" value="${userId}"><br>
```

However for the URL `https://localhost:8443/login?userId=751061`, the browser returns

```
User: <input type="text" name="userId" value=""><br>
```

How can I access the `userId` from the request? I tried `${requestScope.userId}` also.

I've rebuilt the app with `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: A request parameter is NOT "a variable in the request scope". You you should adjust your search keywords to "How do I access a request parameter in JSP?".

Comment: By the way, the `\d` regex also matches non-Latin digits such as Hebrew digits, Arabic digits, Chinese digits, etc. Perhaps you didn't intend that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
public String login(@RequestParam(name="userId", required=true) String userId,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
  ...
  request.setAttribute("userId", userId);
```

Then it was accessible. Rails really spoils you.

https://memorynotfound.com/servlet-attributes-example/

Comment: Don't use `HttpServletRequest`. Use model attributes through `Model` or `ModelMap`.